# Can't paste git ssh link in pycharm git repository url textbox in checkout from version control

Tags: pycharm

When you create a new project in pycharm by selecting the Checkout from version control option --> Git, you get a pop-up window where you can enter the ssh url for the git repo to checkout for your project. In my case, I can select from a dropdown but can't paste into the textbox for it. I get a paste option but selecting it or pressing command+V does nothing. I am completely stumped, any help would be appreciated. Here's a screenshot.[image]

Comment: It has been 9 months, did you find a work around, solution or explanation for this?

Comment: This is also does not work for me under Ubuntu 20.04 when try to create project from "Get from VCS" called from "Welcome to Pycharm" initial page.
Paste url does not work for entering URL. Later in Pycharm paste works fine.